# How to drag and align an item in Android custom view?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-view, draggable, android-custom-view

I created this custom view to add a layer at the top of app

There is a draggable circle in the view

```
public class LockView extends View {

    public LockView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setClickable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(0x55ff0000);
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(LockView.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        ShapeDrawable circle=new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        circle.setBounds(10,10,100,100);
        circle.getPaint().setARGB(0xff,0,0xff,0);
        circle.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
LockView lockView = new LockView(this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams baseParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
addContentView(lockView, baseParams);
```

Question is:

1. How to make the circle draggable? I cannot found any method to set listener to circle.
2. How to align the circle to right bottom?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a listener for drawn objects. After `onDraw()` the circle is a part of a bitmap. Additionally, you should not create objects in `onDraw()` method. To drag the circle, you should override `onTouchEvent()` method, the method gives you various information about the touch event. Then you should keep the position of your circle so you can compare touched point and your circle. For more information, take a look to doc : https://developer.android.com/training/gestures